# How to exclude code block in Intellij IDEA Structural Replace

Tags: intellij-idea, code-inspection, structural-search

I'm creating own inspections based on Structural Replace.
For example I want to make inspection of transforming code like:

```
if (!$Map$.containsKey($key$)){
    $Map$.put($key$, $value$);
}
```

and

```
if ($Map$.get($key$) == null){
    $Map$.put($key$, $value$);
}
```

into

```
$Map$.putIfAbsent($key$, $value$);
```

But I don't want it to react on code like:

```
if (!$Map$.containsKey($key$)){
    $Map$.put($key$, $value$);
}
else {
    // any logic
}
```

I tried to use

```
if (!$Map$.containsKey($key$)){
    $Map$.put($key$, $value$);
}
$else$
```

with option text "else" but it didn't work.

Is it possible? Also I have to make two different inspections with same replace result. Can we use multiple searh pattern?

**UPDATE**:

I tried replace next pattern

```
$Iterable$.forEach($value$ -> {
    if ($condition$) {
        $statement$;
    }
});
```

into

```
$Iterable$.stream()
        .filter($value$ -> $condition$)
        .forEach($value$ -> $statement$);
```

But after replace I'm getting:

```
$Iterable$.stream()
        .filter($value$ -> $condition$)
        .forEach($value$ -> $statement$;);
```

Is it possible to remove ";" from replace result?

Comment: Regarding *Update* ; it looks like you are running into some bugs in Structural Search. Seems like this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Update on your update: the bug is fixed. In IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 your structural replace does not produce extra semicolons any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a search template like this:

```
if (!$Map$.containsKey($key$)){
    $Map$.put($key$, $value$);
} else {
    $statement$;
}
```

Edit variables and set the minimum and maximum count of `statement` to `0`.

Using multiple search patterns for a single Structural Search Inspection is not possible at this time.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.
Also do you know is it possible to make replace with import?
For example replace 
$String$ == null || $String$.isEmpty() to org.apache.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty($String$)

Comment: Enable the `shorten fully qualified names` checkbox in the Structural Replace dialog?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it yesterday. But it didn't work, maybe I had another problem. Could you please answer on one more question in updates, as you are familiar with this topic.